# FileNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: python-3.x, csv, anaconda

help me to resolve this problemi for import a csv file
'''
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 df=pd.read_csv('voci_retributive',index_col='Order Date',parse_dates=True,encoding='ansi', sep=';') #here i am using encoding attribute

```
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    684     )
    685 
--> 686     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    687 
    688 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    450 
    451     # Create the parser.
--> 452     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    453 
    454     if chunksize or iterator:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    944             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    945 
--> 946         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    947 
    948     def close(self):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1176     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
   1177         if engine == "c":
-> 1178             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1179         else:
   1180             if engine == "python":

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1989         if kwds.get("compression") is None and encoding:
   1990             if isinstance(src, str):
-> 1991                 src = open(src, "rb")
   1992                 self.handles.append(src)
   1993 
'''
```

Comment: Are you sure the file is called `voci_retributive` without any extension. And is the path correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the file name argument from 'voci_retributive' to 'voci_retributive.csv' or what ever extension it has